# IEnumerable implementation only for Dictionary values

Tags: c#, ienumerable, enumeration

I have a class, let's say `Player`, with a name and some attributes:

```
public class Players
{
    public string PlayerName { get; set; }
    public IList<Goal> Goals { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I want to create a custom collection class, `PlayerCollection`, but using a Dictionary instead of a list for quicker search. So:

```
public class PlayersCollection
{
    private readonly IDIctionary<string, Player> _players;
    ....
```

Using a dictionary with the player name as the key will make things easier in the rest of my program.
Now I'd like to implement `IEnumerable<Player>`, in order to iterate over the player class, but I can't use the dictionary's enumerator, because it is implemented on `KeyValuePair<string, Player>`.

How can I do that?

Comment: `.select(x=>x.Value)`

Comment: just return `_players.Values.GetEnumerator()`

Comment: `Dictionary` implements same `IEnumerable` as List, just that each element is element is a KeyValuePair, and here Key will be name and Value will be Object

Comment: Any special reason for having a custom `IEnumerable`, there are no same existing collections, which can be effectively used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`KeyedCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438(v=vs.110).aspx) class is perfect for your situation. It lets you look up by a property of members of the collection. The only thing you need to do is create a derived class that has a selector for the property.

```
public class PlayersCollection : KeyedCollection<string, Players>
{
    protected override string GetKeyForItem(Players item)
    {
        return item.PlayerName;
    }
}
```

When you get the enumerator for the `PlayersCollection` it will be a `IEnumerable<Players>`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
public class PlayersCollection : IEnumerable<Player>
{
    private readonly IDictionary<string, Player> _players;

    public IEnumerator<Player> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _players.Select(player => player.Value).GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

If you are looking for a collection with a quick search I suggest you to read about [`HashSet<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) which is part of the framework.

Comment: Actually you should be able to use .Values instead of selecting the values. Performance will be improved